# Using a pre-built db4o database in android app

Tags: android, db4o

Im REALLY struggling to get a pre baked db4o database to work inside my android app.
If i include it in the /res/raw folder then read it, it doesn't work.
If i copy it to the app_data or sdcard then try and read it, it will act as if im opening a new database and provide me with 0 entries on queries.
I was previously just creating all my entries when the app was first opened but as the db grew, so did the creation time to unsustainable levels. 
I would really, really appreciated any help you can give me. It would be perfect if i can include my pre-populated db4o file in the app.
Additional Info:
I have double checked the db4o file with ome and theres no issue with the db creation on my local machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fair point. I have invested alot of my time creating the app with the database creation on first app start, now the databse has grown too big i thought it would be easier todo the creation upfront rather than rip the guts out and re-plumb with sql. Cheers, though if all else fails i think it will be my only route :).

Answer (score 0):

If any one falls into the same trap as me here's the answer:

On android the class is injected into the db4o db with the package name prefixed to the class name by defualt. So accessing from another application will look be looking for +.